# How to write in .env file from python code

Tags: python

I want to write in the .env using python code. This is what I tried but it's not working:-

```
os.environ['username'] = 'John'
os.environ['email'] = 'abc@gmail.com'
```

Comment: Are you trying to set environment variables in the system (permanently), or just change them for your application scope? ``os.environ`` can be changed but will only affect your application, not outside programs.

Comment: Your code is absolutely fine. This sets a new environment variable.

Comment: You can access these during runtime of your program

Comment: That's not exactly true @GaganTK, while the environment variables will be accessible from the current Python process and maybe children processes spawned, they will be lost when the app is closed and restarted. If he wants to change the environment permanently, he should write to ``.profile`` or similar and make an OS dependant solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`os.environ` is a Python dictionary containing the environment. In order to change the environment variables **in your currently running process, and any children process spawned with `fork`**, you should use `os.putenv` as follows:

```py
import os
os.putenv("username", "John")
os.putenv("email", "abc@gmail.com")
```

Do notice, **this changes are not permanent**, they just affect the process being currently executed.

If you want the changes to be permanent, you can write them to a `.env` file, and read and reset them on startup:

```py
with open(".env", "r") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        try:
            key, value = line.split('=')
            os.putenv(key, value)
        except ValueError:
            # syntax error
            pass
```

To generate the file you should:

```py
with open(".env", "w") as f:
    f.write("username=John")
    f.write("email=abc@gmail.com")
```

If you want to permanently change this environment variables on the whole OS scope, you need an OS specific solution, since each operating system has its way of changing environment variables.

This method will set the environment variable **globally**, which will affect all applications run and not just yours, so be extremely careful on what are you writing to.

Unix-like systems like Linux and macOS let you set up these variables in `.profile`, so you may do something like this (Python 3.5+):

```py
from pathlib import Path
with open(str(Path.home()) + "/.profile", "a") as f:
    f.write("export USERNAME=John\nexport EMAIL abc@gmail.com\n")
```

On Windows on the other hand you should call `setx`:

```py
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["setx", "USERNAME", "John"])
subprocess.call(["setx", "EMAIL", "abc@gmail.com"])
```

Comment: How can we save the boolean value in the env using write:-                                            
with open(".env", "w") as f:
    f.write("status=True")

It's getting saved as string.

Comment: Environment variables are always strings. If you want to convert then to boolean, just parse it like ``status = os.environ["status"]=="True"``. Do not attempt ``putenv`` with booleans.

Comment: @MarcSances No exists any special method in dotenv or os modules?

Answer (score 8):

I would like to answer the OP question and speak to the comment by @salius. You can manage your .env files with the package `python-dotenv` in a principled way. It handles validating the key/value pairs and saving them to a file.

Minimal working example:

`$ python3 -m pip install python-dotenv`

```py
from dotenv import set_key
from pathlib import Path


env_file_path = Path("/path/to/new/.env")
# Create the file if it does not exist.
env_file_path.touch(mode=0o600, exist_ok=False)
# Save some values to the file.
set_key(dotenv_path=env_file_path, key_to_set="USERNAME", value_to_set="John")
set_key(dotenv_path=env_file_path, key_to_set="EMAIL", value_to_set="abc@gmail.com")
```

Here is the resulting .env file:

`$ cat /path/to/new/.env`

```
USERNAME='John'
EMAIL='abc@gmail.com'
```